# Grid method tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I'm having problems with positioning multiple button widgets in the same row but, in different columns obviously.  When I try to position them they wont move to where I want them; one seems to influence the rest and they all end up at the top of the root window and not where I want them?  What could be causing this?  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("1240x850")
root.resizable(0,0)

Button(root,width=10, bg="light blue", text="Played").grid(row=150,column = 2)
Button(root,width=10, bg="yellow", text="Goals").grid(row=150,column = 3)
Button(root,width=10, bg="light green", text="Won").grid(row=150,column = 4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please provide some code.

Comment: without code we can do nothing. except sending you to documentation.

Comment: did you use `grid(row=0, column=0)` ?

Comment: No..grid(row=150, column=2) etc same row different columns. Each button is width=10.

Comment: show code and describe what result you expect.

Comment: from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("1240x850")
root.resizable(0,0)
Button(root,width=10, bg="light blue", text="Played").grid(row=150,column = 2)
Button(root,width=10, bg="yellow", text="Goals").grid(row=150,column = 3)
Button(root,width=10, bg="light green", text="Won").grid(row=150,column = 4)
root.mainloop()

Comment: I expected the buttons to be 150 rows down from the top left hand corner of the window 0,0.  Not at the top as I am getting?

Answer (score 2):

Empty rows take up zero space. The same goes for empty columns. If you have two widgets, one at row 1 and one at row 1000, you will get exactly the same behavior as if you have one at row 1 and one at row 2.